# Use parameters in function as key

Tags: javascript, vue.js

Hi anyone gives me some ideas to use the parameters as key in function?

for example, i am using vue, and have set html

```
<div id="app">
  <input ref="name" />
  <button @click="focusIt('name')">
    Click me
  </button>
</div>
```

and javascript code

```
new Vue({
    el: "#app",
  methods: {
    focusIt(value) {
        this.$refs.name.focus();
    }
  }
})
```

I have passed `name` as a parameter in the `focusIt` function, is there any way to use it inside the function as a key? something like  `this.$refs.name.focus()`?

I have made a [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/x69chen/nnf4p1sw/1/)

Thanks for any advice!

**Update**:

I tried the `this.$refs[value].focus()`, but it does not work
[jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/x69chen/nnf4p1sw/15/)

Comment: Your fiddle works as expected (didn't you forget to choose Vue in list of frameworks?). What is the problem?

Comment: `this.$refs[value].focus();`

Comment: @ArunPJohny it is not working, you can try with the jsfiddle i gave.

Comment: @JamesChen https://jsfiddle.net/nnf4p1sw/16/ - you need to add vue library reference

Comment: @ArunPJohny I tried this way before! Did not know why it was not working at that time, and now it works... Thanks anyway

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to pass down the name of the ref:

```
new Vue({
    el: "#app",
    methods: {
    focusIt(value) {
        this.$refs[value].focus();
    }
  }
})
```